# Spawning objects parallel to the terrain

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, quaternions, procedural-generation

**Story**
so I'm working on making a procedural terrain generator script to spawn rocks on the ground all the big rocks don't care what rotation they are but I have some small rocks that have to be parallel to the terrain or they look weird, part of them floating off the ground other part stuck in the ground the quaternions I don't seem to understand

**Problem**
i am getting **the terrainData.GetInterpolatedNormal** and putting it into a **vector3** called **normals** then when i am spawning my rock i rotate it towards ground

```cs
Instantiate(SmallRock, new Vector3(point.x, Heights, point.y) transform.rotation = new Quaternion(normals.x,normals.y, normals.z, 90));
```

my problem lies in the **Quaternion(normals.x,normals.y, normals.z, 90)**
I don't know what to put where like should I only put the **normals.x/z** there or should I put the **normals.y** in there too and I don't even know what **90** at the end does, and yes I know that the **interpolatednormals** returns a 0 to 1 so I tried multiplying it to make it rotate more than 1 but it seems to just not rotate the right way if you can't tell by now I really have no clue how quaternions work but everywhere i search I can't find anything that helps and I didn't really feel like learning about how quaternions work so thanks for saving me time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Quaternions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3BR8tK-LuB0) use compound(Imaginary) numbers to represent a sequence of rotations in 3d space.

When you instantiate a new `Quaternion` using it's constructor you are providing it with what you think the `Quaternion`'s real and imaginary numbers should be.

Despite the seemingly familiar `x`, `y`, and `z` names you should not manually modify or provided them, they are not euler angles, cartesian coordinates, or traditional vector components.

What you're currently passing it is portions of a direction instead of the real and imaginary parts of a `Quaternion`.

A normal is an "outwards direction" from a given position. So to get a rotation we need some other direction to compare it to in order to get a rotation.

[Compare your direction](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.FromToRotation.html) with the up direction and you'll get a rotation that you can use.

```cs
Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, normalDirection);
```